# how to purge/delete database-contens for (functional) tests in playframework

Tags: java, playframework, fixtures, sqlexception

play framework: 1.2.3

Hi,

I am trying to purge my database by using play's fixtures. However, I run into some problems  trying that.

First, Fixtures.deleteDatabase() deletes the whole database and play does not recreate it on another test (also I haven't found nothing to do so.

Second, trying to deleteAllModules() I get an exception for any model play is trying to delete:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting
```

These models have been created during the test using the normal Model.save(). I suppose that - once again - transactions come into my way somehow. However, looking at the database, all models get persisted.

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    new Job() {
        @Override
        public void doJob() throws Exception {
            Logger.debug("[SetupUtils.createClearDBJob().new Job() {...}] Deleting database");
            Fixtures.deleteAllModels();
            //              Fixtures.delete()
            //              Fixtures.deleteDatabase();
        }
    }.now().get();
}
```

Full-Stacktrace

```
ERROR 563 :play#niceThrowable - While deleting class models.DropboxFolder instances
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute update query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1224)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:108)
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin$JPAModelLoader.deleteAll(JPAPlugin.java:478)
    at play.test.Fixtures.delete(Fixtures.java:72)
    at play.test.Fixtures.delete(Fixtures.java:92)
    at play.test.Fixtures.deleteAllModels(Fixtures.java:104)
    at mashpan.utilities.SetupUtils$2.doJob(SetupUtils.java:44)
    at play.jobs.Job.doJobWithResult(Job.java:50)
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:146)
    at play.jobs.Job$1.call(Job.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute update query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1288)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:99)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2325)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:101)
    ... 21 more
ERROR 563 :play#niceThrowable - While deleting class models.User instances
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute update query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1224)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:108)
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin$JPAModelLoader.deleteAll(JPAPlugin.java:478)
    at play.test.Fixtures.delete(Fixtures.java:72)
    at play.test.Fixtures.delete(Fixtures.java:92)
    at play.test.Fixtures.deleteAllModels(Fixtures.java:104)
    at mashpan.utilities.SetupUtils$2.doJob(SetupUtils.java:44)
    at play.jobs.Job.doJobWithResult(Job.java:50)
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:146)
    at play.jobs.Job$1.call(Job.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at 


java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute update query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1288)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:99)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2325)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:101)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem, you have to first deleteDatabase that deletes everything in the db and after create data for example with Fixtures.loadModels : what else do you need ?

Comment: Fixtures.deleteDatabase() deletes the whole database and play does not recreate it on the next test so loading models also fails. so I can not do that.
I am looking for a way to delete all rows in all tables but nothing else. Another approach would be deleting all tables or even deleting the database as whole and then let play recreate it. however, didn't find a way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the create/delete operaton in the Bootstrap, and to check if Play! is running in test mode or production mode.

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job {

  public void doJob() {
    if (Play.mode == Play.Mode.DEV) {
        DropboxFolder.deleteAll(); // delete 
        Fixtures.load("samples_data.yml"); // recreate 
    }
  }
}
```